# Long running process in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

We have a long running report which is now scheduled using Reporting Services. This report runs around 40 minutes and produces a csv report of around 10 MB of data. We are now building a new Asp.Net MVC app and the user wants us to bring this long running report into ASP.Net MVC and retire the Reporting services. Initially we thought of doing it with Task.Run/HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem but we moved away due to app domain recycle issues and we do not want our worker process to take this load.

Currently, we are planning to build a command line C# exe which can run the stored procedure and prepare the CSV report into a shared folder. We will then have a ASP.Net MVC view from where user can initiate the command line exe through system.diagnostics.process.start() method. The ASP.NET MVC will show the report as downloadable link once the process is completed. We will have a status DB table which the exe can update the status once the process completes and the Asp.Net MVC view can use this to display the status and downloadable report.

Is there a better way of handling this requirement? Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bala

Comment: Why is the user deciding any technological decisions? From a technological view, a reporting service to generate long running reports sounds excellent. Why retire it?

Comment: A better approach is to have a dedicated service (not web service) listening for report requests.  Use message queuing so the message is persisted, and return it to the queue or unlock it in case the service fails.  40 minutes is a really long process that should be broken into pieces (CQRS, workflow, saga, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the Windows Service approach. The main reason is that you can keep an eye on how many instances are running at the same time and throttle it if you need to. You don't get the same kind of control with an exe. Use the same status approach, that will work fine.

You are right to keep this out of the Web App, you really don't want to put that kind of pressure on it. You could even run the service on a different server to keep the web one lighter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid-enough approach, I think. However, running an EXE requires a full trust environment, which is generally not a good idea. Personally, I would use something like [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/), instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Let me check HangFire too.